# Bad fetch request (NSManagedObjectResultType not compatible with contents of propertiesToFetch) after updating to Swift 1.2 (XCode 6.3)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I am having an issue with my `Core Data` methods of fetching results after updating to `Swift 1.2/XCode 6.3`.

Below is an example of a fetch method for Core Data. I am just trying to retrieve the objectID from the entry. It was working before I updated to Swift 1.2.

Anyone have the same issue? And how would I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

**Fetching from Core Data method**

```
func getExistingGameObjectId(id: String) -> NSManagedObjectID? {
    let objectIdDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
    objectIdDesc.name = "objectID"
    objectIdDesc.expression = NSExpression.expressionForEvaluatedObject()
    objectIdDesc.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.ObjectIDAttributeType

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Game")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [objectIdDesc]

    var error: NSError?
    if let results = parentContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) {
        if error == nil {
            if !results.isEmpty {
                if let objectId = results[0].valueForKey("objectID") as? NSManagedObjectID {
                    return objectId
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            println("Fetch Game Object ID Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
2015-04-20 15:53:18.699 LovelUp[3466:39098] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Bad fetch request (NSManagedObjectResultType not compatible with contents of propertiesToFetch)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba0bc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ddf6bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreData                            0x000000010b20ab6e -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 1646
    3   CoreData                            0x000000010b1f6dc4 -[NSSQLAdapter _statementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 244
    4   CoreData                            0x000000010b10ee0c -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 316
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010b10ea86 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 118
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010b10e33c -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 524
    7   CoreData                            0x000000010b10ddbb -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 299
    8   CoreData                            0x000000010b1e8a6c __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3356
    9   CoreData                            0x000000010b1f1c30 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 192
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ed6f614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ed55002 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365
    12  CoreData                            0x000000010b1e3245 _perform + 197
    13  CoreData                            0x000000010b10da58 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504
    14  CoreData                            0x000000010b10c2ca -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 586
    15  LovelUp                             0x000000010a48aab2 _TFC7LovelUp14DatabaseHelper23getExistingGameObjectIdfS0_FSSGSqCSo17NSManagedObjectID_ + 1186
    16  LovelUp                             0x000000010a48bca3 _TFC7LovelUp14DatabaseHelper10updateGamefS0_FCS_4GameT_ + 179
    17  LovelUp                             0x000000010a440da2 _TFC7LovelUp10JsonParser13parseGameJsonfS0_FV10SwiftyJSON4JSONGSqCS_4Game_ + 2354
    18  LovelUp                             0x000000010a3b7052 _TFC7LovelUp18HttpResponseHelper17handleGameInfoGetfS0_FV10SwiftyJSON4JSONT_ + 1042
    19  LovelUp                             0x000000010a3b5d0a _TFC7LovelUp18HttpResponseHelper14handleResponsefS0_FTSS4jsonV10SwiftyJSON4JSON_T_ + 1226
    20  LovelUp                             0x000000010a4756ec _TFZFC7LovelUp14HttpPostHelper8sendPostFMS0_FTSS10parametersGVSs10DictionarySSPSs9AnyObject___T_U0_FTCSo12NSURLRequestGSqCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse_GSqPS2___GSqCSo7NSError__T_ + 444
    21  LovelUp                             0x000000010a46b1ac _TPA__TFZFC7LovelUp14HttpPostHelper8sendPostFMS0_FTSS10parametersGVSs10DictionarySSPSs9AnyObject___T_U0_FTCSo12NSURLRequestGSqCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse_GSqPS2___GSqCSo7NSError__T_ + 108
    22  Alamofire                           0x000000010aa249ee _TFFC9Alamofire7Request12responseJSONFDS0_FT7optionsVSC20NSJSONReadingOptions17completionHandlerFTCSo12NSURLRequestGSqCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse_GSqPSs9AnyObject__GSqCSo7NSError__T__DS0_U_FTS2_GSqS3__GSqPS4___GSqS5___T_ + 126
    23  Alamofire                           0x000000010aa20e33 _TFFFC9Alamofire7Request8responseFDS0_FT5queueGSqCSo8NSObject_10serializerFTCSo12NSURLRequestGSqCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse_GSqCSo6NSData__TGSqPSs9AnyObject__GSqCSo7NSError__17completionHandlerFTS2_GSqS3__GSqPS5___GSqS6___T__DS0_U_FT_T_U_FT_T_ + 403
    24  Alamofire                           0x000000010aa1e5a7 _TTRXFo__dT__XFdCb__dT__ + 39
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ed50186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ed6f614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ed57a1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9731f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b934dcb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b934366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001125a8a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010cb2a900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    33  LovelUp                             0x000000010a36bb17 main + 135
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010eda3145 start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Try setting your fetch to dictionaryResultType: `fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType`.

Comment: @pbasdf This fixed it! Thank you! I also experimented and commented out `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [objectIdDesc]` and it also ran with no problems. And seems like I was able to retrieve the `objectID`. Although I would be pulling a bunch of other info that I don't use. Please make an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your fetch to dictionaryResultType:

```
fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```

As you've found, you can also fetch the complete NSManagedObject (by removing `propertiesToFetch`).

One other option, which I haven't tried, is to specify resultType of `NSManagedObjectIDResultType`, which will (I think) avoid fetching all the other properties of the objects, and you need not then use `valueForKey`:

```
if let objectId = results[0] as? NSManagedObjectID {
    return objectId
}
```